# Tkinter double tk.Text wont scroll with the same scrollbar

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit, tkinter-text

I want the scrollbar to scroll both `tk.Text`. I tried many things, like a function for the `tk.Scrollbar`: `(command=self.multiple_scroll)` and this current configuration:

```
self.reader = tk.Toplevel(self)
self.reader.title("XXX")
self.reader.resizable(False, True)
self.reader.geometry("650x500")
self.reader.minsize(650,150)

self.panel = tk.Text(self.reader, wrap="word", width=12, font=('Courier',14))
self.viewer = tk.Text(self.reader, wrap="word", font=('Courier',14))
self.scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self.reader, command=(self.panel.yview, self.viewer.yview))

self.panel.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)
self.viewer.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)

self.scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")
self.panel.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
self.viewer.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand=True)
```

When I scroll with the scroll wheel, the Text that is under my cursor moves, but not the other. I need to keep the two `tk.Text` separated.

[image: Here is a picture]

Comment: `command=(self.panel.yview, self.viewer.yview)` does not execute `self.panel.yview` and `self.viewer.yview`.  You can use `lambda` instead: `command=lambda *args: (self.panel.yview(*args), self.viewer.yview(*args))`.  For mouse wheel issue, you need to bind `<MouseWheel>` on both `self.panel` and `self.viewer` and scroll the two text boxes inside the bind callback.  Other than the mouse wheel issue, you need to synchronise the two boxes when one of the text box is scrolled by keyboard as well.

Comment: @acw1668 tho at the end you shouldn't use lambda for multiple function calls, simply define a separate function and call that

Comment: see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32038701/python-tkinter-making-two-text-widgets-scrolling-synchronize

Answer (score 1):

copying from here: [Python tkinter, Making two text widget's scrolling synchronize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32038701/python-tkinter-making-two-text-widgets-scrolling-synchronize) and of course from more important here: [Multiple commands to a button in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42001435/multiple-commands-to-a-button-in-tkinter) that says:

`To do "two things with one button", the correct solution is to create a function that does these "two things", and then associate that function with the button.`

I ended up with:

import tkinter as tk

```
class MainApplication(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.reader= parent
        
        # self.reader = tk.Toplevel(self)
        self.reader.title("XXX")
        self.reader.resizable(False, True)
        self.reader.geometry("650x50")
        self.reader.minsize(650,150)
        
        self.panel = tk.Text(self.reader, wrap="word", width=12, font=('Courier',14))
        self.viewer = tk.Text(self.reader, wrap="word", font=('Courier',14))
        # self.scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self.reader, command=(self.panel.yview, self.viewer.yview))
        
        self.scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self.reader, command=(self.on_scrollbar))
        
        #self.panel.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)
        #self.viewer.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)
        
        self.scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        self.panel.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.viewer.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand=True)
        
        
        
        # Changing the settings to make the scrolling work
        # self.scrollbar['command'] = self.on_scrollbar
        self.panel['yscrollcommand'] = self.on_textscroll
        self.viewer['yscrollcommand'] = self.on_textscroll
        
        
    def on_scrollbar(self, *args):
        """
        Scrolls both text widgets when the scrollbar is moved
        """
        self.panel.yview(*args)
        self.viewer.yview(*args)
            
    def on_textscroll(self, *args):
        '''Moves the scrollbar and scrolls text widgets when the mousewheel
        is moved on a text widget'''
        self.scrollbar.set(*args)
        self.on_scrollbar('moveto', args[0])



if __name__ == "__main__":
    master = tk.Tk()
   
    MainApplication(master)  
    master.mainloop()
```

let us know if it works as expected, what I have noticed is that once one of the two Text reaches the end the other one keeps going having the two texts non-aligned in a window that is smaller than the longest text. Not sure how to handle that, need to find a way to add empty lines so that the two text have same lenght, let me know if is there anything better